# javascript- regular expression alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to allow alphanumeric and some special characters

```
var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9._-\] ]+$/;
```

I tried escaping the ] sign with the forward slash  but it still doesnt work.
What am I missing

Comment: what are you testing, and what went wrong?

Comment: I believe you mean the backslash(\\), not the forward slash (/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to escape the `-` character:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9._\-\] ]+$/
//------------^
```

Escaping `-` is not always necessary. Here, however, it is used inside square brackets which makes the JavaScript engine assume that you are trying to specify the range from `_-]` which causes a "Range out of order in character class" error.

Note that `/[_-a]/` is valid regex and matches characters `_`, `` ` `` and `a` (ASCII codes 95...97); which may not be the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you try your regex on an online regex tester like regex101 you'd get the error:

**[Regex link](http://regex101.com/r/nZ6lA2/1)**

[image]

You have to escape `-` using `\-`:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._\-\] ]+$
```

Btw, you can shorten your regex to:

```
^[\w.\-% ]+$
```

Edit: added regex for your comment:

```
^[\w.-\]\[ #$>()@{}'"]+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/nZ6lA2/2)**

Comment: I modified the  regex : var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9._-%  ]+$/; I included % and now when I run it in Chrome I get syntax error range out of order in character class. I would like to include special characters like #$>[]()@{}'" and alphanumeric.

Comment: @Mary I've updated my answer for your comment. Regex has special characters that need to be escaped, so dash is one that you need to escape it as \-. Btw, if your question is answered you may consider marking your question as solved